# É possível definir um pool de conexão para cada usuário de uma base de dados oracle?

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, oracle, session, conexão

[image: O padrão e este da imagem, mas eu gostaria de criar um diferente para cada usuário]

Procurei na documentação oracle e só encontro maneiras de alterar este da imagem, mas nada a respeito de criar outro. Alguém aí sabe se é possível o que estou requisitando? E como proceder?

Desde já agradeço.
Att
Harisson Ford A. Ribeiro

Comment: Olhou na documentação de referência? http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/java.112/e12265/manage.htm#BABICIII

Comment: @GiulianaBezerra, verifiquei sim, mas se você observar, existem apenas definições para alterar o pool padrão de conexão, não encontro nada referente à criar (Um pool para cada usuário do banco).

Comment: Ah, vi aqui, de fato é tudo em cima de um único pool manager. Bem interessante sua pergunta, vou dar uma olhada aqui pra ver se acho algo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mais ou menos, é possível configurar no banco de dados um limite de sessões por usuário não um pool de conexões. Para isso podemos criar e configurar profiles, graças a este recurso podemos controlar coisas como:

- Total de sessões por usuário
- Consumo de CPU por usuário
- Tempo máximo de conexão

Muitas outras possibilidades são possíveis graças as profiles de usuário. Consulte o link a seguir para maiores informações a respeito do assunto: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/statements_6010.htm#SQLRF01310

Para alterar a profile de um usuário consulte: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4003.htm

Agora vou explicar o motivo pelo qual respondi "mais ou menos". O pool de conexões normalmente é configurado na sua aplicação, por exemplo, se você tiver uma aplicação Java rodando sobre um Tomcat o pool de conexões pode ser gerenciado pela aplicação Java, ou mais comumente pelo Tomcat. Já do lado do banco de dados você controla características como:

- Limite de conexões por usuário
- Tempo máximo de inatividade antes de
  encerrar a sessão
- Tempo máximo de sessão etc...